# Let $S:U\rightarrow V, \ T:V\rightarrow W$ be linear map. And if $TS$ is surjective, Can this imply $T$ is injective?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S:U\rightarrow V, \ T:V\rightarrow W$ be linear map. And if $TS$ is surjective,  Can this imply $T$ is injective?

Of course $T$ is surhective. But for injective, there comes out some problem. I am wondering if $T$ is not injective, maybe $TS$ won't be well defined. But I can't find a counterexample either. Thanks for hints.

Comment: $TS$ surjective implies $T$ surjective. $TS$ injective implies $S$ injective. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Take $U=V=\mathbb{R^n},W=\{0\}$ and let $S$ be the identity transformation, $T$ the zero transformation. Of course $T$ is not injective and of course $TS:U\to W$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for $TS$ to be surjective but $T$ to not be injective.  For instance, consider
$$
T = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0}, \quad S =\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1\\0&0} 
$$